# Cannot Install Ionic cordova-res

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

While running the command `ionic cordova resources` I am getting this error:

> ```
> cordova-res.cmd
> [cordova-res] module.js:549
> [cordova-res]     throw err;
> [cordova-res]     ^
> [cordova-res]
> [cordova-res] Error: Cannot find module 'F:\Ionic\myApp\node_modules\cordova-res\bin\cordova-res'
> [cordova-res]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
> [cordova-res]     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
> [cordova-res]     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
> [cordova-res]     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
> [cordova-res]     at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova-res.
>         cordova-res.cmd exited with exit code 1.
>         Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
> And while installing cordova-res i am getting this error:
> npm install cordova-res -g
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for cordova-res@0.14.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.3.0"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: cordova-res@0.14.0
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for @ionic/utils-fs@3.1.2: wanted: {"node":">=10.3.0"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: @ionic/utils-fs@3.1.2
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for sharp@0.25.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: sharp@0.25.2
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for fs-extra@9.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: fs-extra@9.0.0
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for universalify@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">= 10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: universalify@1.0.0
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for tar@6.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 10"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: tar@6.0.2
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for semver@7.3.2: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: semver@7.3.2
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for chownr@2.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: chownr@2.0.0
> npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for mkdirp@1.0.4: wanted: {"node":">=10"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})
> npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: mkdirp@1.0.4
> npm ERR! code EEXIST
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\manav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\bin\cordova-res
> npm ERR! dest C:\Users\manav\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova-res
> npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\manav\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova-res\bin\cordova-res' -> 'C:\Users\manav\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova-res'
> npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\manav\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova-res
> npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
> npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\manav\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-09T22_09_12_401Z-debug.log
> ```

Check this out and help me get out of it.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

as the error says...

**npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for cordova-res@0.14.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.3.0"} (current: {"node":"8.11.3","npm":"6.14.5"})**

you need higher version of node....
try checking the current versiona and try updating it..

Comment: Have the same problem as the OP. But it seems, version 6.14.5 is the current version of npm available.... at least via download from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ -- how to install any more recent version then?